# Should I exclude .slconfig from source control?

Tags: sonarlint

I am using SonarLint in my .NET core project. When integrating projects with SonarLint, the following files are generated inside a `.sonarlint` folder:

- `<SonarQubeProject>CSharp.ruleset`
- `<Solution>.slconfig`

The `.ruleset` file contains the rules for sonarlint and sonarqube, so I'm already keeping this file in source control.

But what about the `.slconfig`? Should I keep this file in source control or should I exclude it? (add it to `.gitignore` in my case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This file **should** be included in source control.

This file controls synchronization between source code and SQ.
It includes among others:

- `ServerUri` pointing to the SonarQube server to which this project is bound to.
- `ProjectKey` with the key of the project in the SQ server
- Profiles which includes a `ProfileKey` that is an identifier for the Quality profile selected in the server.

Source: This post from the SonarSource community: [SonarLint source control](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-source-control/2892/2)

Comment: From the linked article: "If your SonarQube server requires user credentials (i.e. doesn’t allow anonymous access) then the credentials you provide will be stored in the Windows Credential Manager."